# Is there a way to get the PyPDF2 library to recognize foreign language characters

Tags: python, pdf

Basically, I am creating a programme to convert receipts into a excel file. The problem though that I run into is that I am mostly using Polish receipts (as I am polish) which have several unique characters which the programme does not recognize. Are there other libraries or a sub-library I can download for this or something else I can do to fix the problem?

I haven't found any info on a solution online so far,

Comment: Seems odd that any library wouldn't handle utf8. You could check if your pdf is in utf8 or some other charset, then check how to configure your library to use that. A [mcve] would be helpful. Also note that requests for libraries are off-topic here.